# Is the space of positive linear functionals on a $C^{*}$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ closed in the norm topology of $\mathcal{A}^{*}$?

Tags: operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra and $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ its Banach dual.
Let $\mathcal{P}\subset \mathcal{A}^{*}$ be the convex set of positive linear functionals on $\mathcal{A}$.
Is $\mathcal{P}$ closed in the norm topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is positive if your $C^*$ algebra $A$ has a unit, say, $e$. In that case, there is a theorem asserting that a bounded functional is positive on $A$ if and only if its norm is attained at $e$.
Therefore, if $f_n\to f$ in norm, then $|f_n(e)-f(e)|\to 0$, and also $f_n(e)=\|f_n\|\to\|f\|$, hence $f(e)=\|f\|$ so $f$ is a positive functional.

Comment: Very nice!! Am I wrong, or is this result not explicitly stated in texts like those of Blackadar or Bratteli-Robinson? It seems to me that the norm-topological properties of positive linear functionals are thought to be not so interesting...

Comment: Perhaps the reason is that the set of positive functionals, per-se, is not even bounded in the norm ($f(e)$ can be as large as you wish), so it being closed is not much useful anyway. On the other hand, the positive functionals whose norm is exactly $1$, form what is called the state space, and the extreme points are pure states, and in the weak-star topology this becomes compact, which is quite useful. Finally, they have to save some facts for the problem sections of their books.

Comment: This answer makes it sound like the answer is no when $A$ is not unital. But a norm limit of positive functionals is positive even if $A$ is not unital. Its just the fact that norm convergence implies pointwise convergence.

Comment: @MartinArgerami are you referring to the possibility of using approximate identities to perform the same proof?

Comment: @uniquesolution my interest in the norm topology is essentially driven by differential geometric considerations. Therefore, the weak* topology is "less useful" leading to a manifold structure which is not Banach. On the other hand, I appreciate the insight in your last sentence :)

Comment: If $\|f-f_n\|\to0$, then $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\to0$. So if $x\geq0$ and $f_n(x)\geq0$ for all $n$, then $f(x)=\lim f_n(x)\geq0$.